# applying right margin dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

```
#dock > li ul
        {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: -180px;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 180px;
            display: none;
            background-color: #F1F1F1;
            border: solid 1px #969696;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            list-style: none;
        }
```

This is my css class and I want to apply a right margin dynamically using jquery. Any thoughts appreciated. I tried this:

`$('#dock').children('li').children('ul').css({ 'margin-right': rmargin });`

but it seems to be not working.

Comment: Post your HTML. Also, what is your `rmargin`, where have you defined it?

Comment: You usually can use the same selectors in jQuery as in CSS `$('#dock>li ul').css('margin-right', rmargin);` should work, assuming `rmargin` is a valid value to be assigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('#dock').find('ul').css({ 'margin-right': rmargin });
```

`ul` must be a `child` or a `grand child` of `#dock` other wise it may not works

In that case you can use

```
$('#dock > li ul').css({ 'margin-right': rmargin });
```

Docs http://api.jquery.com/find

Comment: Wouldn't it be more logical to just use the same selector as he posted in his CSS. (No difference in result though.)

Comment: @BramVanroy: The results might is not the necessarily the same. The CSS selector is `#dock > li ul` so by using `$('#dock').find('ul')` you are not looking for the same as you now also will pick up any `ul`s which are **not** inside an `li` which are a direct child of the `#dock` element. Using `$('#dock > li ul').css({ 'margin-right': rmargin })` should work and will make very sure only the same elements are targeted which are also targeted by the CSS.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl That's what I meant. With *no difference in result though* I meant that using `find("ul")` will **also** target `#dock > li ul`. In other words, the `find` method is a set of which the specific css is an object.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#dock > li ul').css({ 'margin-right': rmargin });
```

Comment: One question: *why*? You don't need another class.

Comment: @BramVanroy I've removed the another class code.. It wouldn't have worked. Thanks for specifying.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as below,

```
$('#dock > li ul').css({ 'margin-right': rmargin });
```

`$('#dock > li ul')` this will select all `UL` inside of `LI` tag which is **direct child** of `#dock` DOM.

Comment: `$('#dock li ul')` is not the same as `#dock > li ul`. Your selector will also match any `li`s which are **not** direct children. Possibly causing incorrect elements to be targeted.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl yes it will select all the li which are child of #dock..i have updated it

Comment: I didn't say it will not select them I said you **also** end up selecting unwanted `li`s which are not direct children.